# How to save twitter status objects in redis?

Tags: redis

So, I was thinking of using redis to save twitter status objects. I just started using redis so here is my fundamental doubt:

As I'm using tweepy, I get status objects. I want to store these status objects in redis. I'm using redis-py and would use append command to do it, but I want all the status objects to be unique. Thus, might be a rather stupid question, but should I store it as a value or a key. If I store the status objects as value then how do I know unique values? What is the redis command for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every status in twitter has a unique id.
Why not use that as a key?

```
redis.set(statusid, status)
```